# Cannot run "taskkill" on a bash script, but can run from cygwin

Tags: windows-10, bash, cygwin

I have a very simple Bash Script. The goal of this bash script is to take in a parameter of a port number, and kill all processes running on that port.

```
#!/bin/bash
PID_NUMBER=$(netstat -a -n -b -o | grep $1 | sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g" | cut -d ' ' -f5)
echo "$PID_NUMBER"
taskkill /F /PID "$PID_NUMBER"
```

However, running the bash script in Cygwin echoes the PID_NUMBER, correctly, but throws an "ERROR: Invalid query" for taskkill

Output:

```
$ ./KillProcessesAtPort.sh 546
1540
ERROR: Invalid query
```

If I run "taskkill /F /PID 1540" in Cygwin, the process is sucessfully terminated.

```
$ taskkill /F /PID 1540
SUCCESS: The process with PID 1540 has been terminated.
```

I am running this script in Windows 10 on Cygwin terminal. Why does my script throw an ERROR for taskkill whereas just executing taskkill in Cygwin works?

Comment: Have you tried `taskkill /F /PID $PID_NUMBER` with no quotes?

Comment: Are you sure you did not edit the output of `echo "$PID_NUMBER"`? I encounter problems when the line is repeated more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
PID_NUMBER=$(netstat -a -n -b -o | grep $1 | sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g" | cut -d ' ' -f6 | head -1)
echo "$PID_NUMBER"
taskkill /F /PID "$PID_NUMBER"
```

**Note1:** I had to replace `-f5` with `-f6` because otherwise I'd get a different column.
**Note2:** `taskkill` would fail with `ERROR: Invalid query` when more than one `pid` was returned. Solved by adding `| head -1`.

**Conclusion1:** Be aware that your solution is not robust: since `netstat` can output e.g. `LISTENING` before the `pid` you cannot reliably split the way you did.
**Conclusion2:** You should always pass a single value to `taskkill`, not a multiline string.

**Suggestion:** Differentiate for `UDP` and `TCP`, since `TCP` connections have a `STATUS` column:

```
PID_NUMBER=$(netstat -a -n -o | grep :$1 | awk '/UDP/{a=$4} /TCP/{a=$5} END{print a}')
```